# Migrating Azure AD PowerShell script to Graph API SDK to pull Azure AD Roster

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-ad-graph-api

My company has been preparing for the deprecation of the AzureAD PowerShell module so we implemented Graph API access to our Azure Tenant.  I have the following Admin Consented permissions

- User.Read
- Group.Read.All
- Directory.Read.All
- User.Read.All

My script worked fine with AzureAD but the groups changed with the Graph API SDK and keep getting Cannot Index into a Null Array when having made the changes.

```
param(
     [string] $path = "C:\Temp\ADUsers-$(Get-Date -format "MM-dd-yyyy").csv"
)

& {
foreach($azuser in Get-MgUser -All -Filter 'accountEnabled eq true') {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        "Employee ID"   = $azuser.ExtensionProperty["employeeId"]
        "Last Name"     = $azuser.surname
        "First Name"    = $azuser.givenName
        "Work Email"    = $azuser.UserPrincipalName
        "Job Title"     = $azuser.JobTitle
        "Department"    = $azuser.CompanyName
        "Manager Email" = (Get-MgUserManager -ObjectId $azuser.ObjectId).UserPrincipalName
        "License"       = $azuser.ExtensionProperty["extension_a92af0a4c463"]
        }
    }
} | Export-CSV -Path $path -NoTypeInformation
Invoke-Item $path
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to migrate Migrate from Azure AD PowerShell to the Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK please refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/migration-steps?view=graph-powershell-1.0#convert-your-scripts

For Convert your scripts which were used in old azure ad and check in Microsoft Graph PowerShell:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/migration-steps?view=graph-powershell-1.0#convert-your-scripts
[image]

You can also check out the Cmdlet map for  Microsoft Graph equivalent of your Azure AD PowerShell cmdlets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/microsoftgraph/azuread-msoline-cmdlet-map?view=graph-powershell-1.0